# Display ManyToOne as Selectbox

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-form, zend-framework2, foreign-key-relationship

I'm using `AnnotationForms` and created a valid `Doctrine` ManyToOne relationship. I checked it in the database - its working.

The foreign key field is just displayed as an input field. Is there a way to automatically let the framework create a `Selectbox` which is filled with Objects of the related Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a blog post which covers this issue quite good:

http://blog.james-carr.org/2012/09/16/using-select-in-zend-framework-2/